# How to make result all in one window in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for (Vehicle r : resultList) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,r.getPlate() + " " + r.getYear() + " " +
                   r.getMfg() + " " + r.getStyle() + " " +
                   r.getColor() + "\t");
}
```

So I have an array, I know it's in in a loop, but this is the closest I got... Could someone help me how to get result in one window? And separated by tab?

Comment: Create the whole string in the loop and show the message after the loop...

Comment: nice it did work, how to get rid of , and []?

Comment: Update the code and what [] ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a string before your loop and append that text to the string in the loop. Then when you exit out of the loop simply display your string.

Edit: Your original code doesn't have newlines at all so yeah. For tabs, wrap the string in a `JTextArea`. Play around with the `"\n\t"` string because I'm not quite sure if that's what you want.

```
for (Vehicle r : resultList) {
    message += r.getPlate() + " " + r.getYear() + " " +
            r.getMfg() + " " + r.getStyle() + " " +
            r.getColor() + "\n\t";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(message));
```

Comment: yeah but then its all in one line... and \t doesnt work